# Android XML How to set background gradient inside a custom shape button

Tags: android, xml

I am creating a button shape look like WWTBAM game show:

[image]

I have created the shape for it but don't know how to put the gradient in it.

This is my styles.xml file I created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ButtonShapeArrow">
        <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And button in layout_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    app:shapeAppearance="@style/ButtonShapeArrow"/>
```

How do I set gradient for that button?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom background, you can change `angle` to change to position of the gradient

**bg_gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <gradient
         android:angle="270"
         android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
         android:startColor="#802BC0E4" />
</shape>
```